# 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'build_absolute_uri'

Tags: python, django

AttributeError at /blog/8/share/

'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'build_absolute_uri'

Request Method:     POST
Request URL:        localhost

Django Version:     1.8.6

Exception Type:     AttributeError
Exception Value:

'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'build_absoulte_uri'

Traceback:
File "/home/shaik/code/my_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response

132. response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
     File "/home/shaik/code/mysite/blog/views.py" in post_share
133. post_url=request.build_absoulte_uri(post.get_absolute_url())

Exception Type: AttributeError at /blog/8/share/

Exception Value: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'build_absolute_uri'

Answer (score 2):

You are having a typo in method name. 
It's `build_absolute_uri` not `build_absoulte_uri`

Comment: The typo is from my end

Comment: Are you sure? Cause even after your previous edit that you fixed 3 occurrences there are still 2 more occurrences of this typo. Besides, if it was written right there shouldn't be such error. So I suggest you to check line 133 of blog/views.py one more time.

Answer (score 0):

You might have implemented a context processor in middleware due which the data is not available in views. you may required to create your own custome middleware.